# Mailgun Internal Server Error 500 when attempting to send mail

Tags: python, heroku, flask, mailgun

When I send mail through mailgun API on my localhost it works fine, however when I try and send it through my web app (Hosted by Heroku, built with Python), there seems to be an internal server error.

[image: Img of error]

My API key and URL are stored in a environment variable.

And in Heroku I have added the following config vars

`MAILGUN_URL`: https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mycustomdomain.io/messages

`MAILGUN_API`: my api key.

Why does this API work with localhost but not on my application? My application does have an SSL certificate.

Full Logs

```
2018-09-16T16:49:35.715559+00:00 app[web.1]: {address space usage: 356995072 bytes/340MB} {rss usage: 30208000 bytes/28MB} [pid: 7|app: 0|req: 2/2] 10.182.99.110 () {52 vars in 1007 bytes} [Sun Sep 16 16:49:35 2018] GET /forgotpw => generated 9702 bytes in 14 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 81 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.619559+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/getnewpassword" host=www.zappay.io request_id=745b2c33-b7df-4334-a634-117d97d5e5ea fwd="115.73.216.193" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=105ms status=500 bytes=375 protocol=https
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615016+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-09-16 16:49:38,609] ERROR in app: Exception on /getnewpassword [POST]
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615032+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615034+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615037+00:00 app[web.1]: body=body, headers=headers)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615039+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615040+00:00 app[web.1]: self._validate_conn(conn)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615042+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 782, in _validate_conn
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615044+00:00 app[web.1]: conn.connect()
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615045+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 250, in connect
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615047+00:00 app[web.1]: ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615048+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 285, in ssl_wrap_socket
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615050+00:00 app[web.1]: return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615051+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615053+00:00 app[web.1]: _context=self, _session=session)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615055+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615056+00:00 app[web.1]: self.do_handshake()
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615058+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615059+00:00 app[web.1]: self._sslobj.do_handshake()
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615063+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615065+00:00 app[web.1]: self._sslobj.do_handshake()
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615067+00:00 app[web.1]: ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615069+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615071+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615072+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615073+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615075+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 369, in send
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615076+00:00 app[web.1]: timeout=timeout
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615078+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 588, in urlopen
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615079+00:00 app[web.1]: raise SSLError(e)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615081+00:00 app[web.1]: requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615082+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615084+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615085+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615087+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615101+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615103+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615105+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615106+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615108+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615110+00:00 app[web.1]: reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615111+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615113+00:00 app[web.1]: raise value
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615114+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615116+00:00 app[web.1]: rv = self.dispatch_request()
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615117+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615119+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615120+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./src/app.py", line 136, in new_pw
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615122+00:00 app[web.1]: user.send_simple_message()
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615123+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./src/models/user.py", line 131, in send_simple_message
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615125+00:00 app[web.1]: "text": self.verification_code})
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615126+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 109, in post
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615127+00:00 app[web.1]: return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615130+00:00 app[web.1]: response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615129+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615132+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 471, in request
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615133+00:00 app[web.1]: resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615134+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 579, in send
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615136+00:00 app[web.1]: r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615137+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 430, in send
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615139+00:00 app[web.1]: raise SSLError(e, request=request)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615140+00:00 app[web.1]: requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749)
2018-09-16T16:49:38.615847+00:00 app[web.1]: {address space usage: 357269504 bytes/340MB} {rss usage: 32284672 bytes/30MB} [pid: 7|app: 0|req: 3/3] 10.182.99.110 () {60 vars in 1164 bytes} [Sun Sep 16 16:49:38 2018] POST /getnewpassword => generated 291 bytes in 102 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 84 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please avoid posting images of text. Images can't be searched, copied, or processed by assistive technology like screen readers. Instead, paste the text directly into your question, then select it and click `{}` or press Ctrl+K. This will indent it, causing Stack Overflow to format it as code.

Comment: It's hard to tell since there isn't much context, but it looks like _your_ code is rejecting _Mailgun's_ certificate. Please [edit] your question to add more context from that traceback and the relevant source code that it references.